# ChkTex on Windows

Tags: bash, cygwin, sublime-text-3

I'm trying to install the [`SublimeLinter-chktex`](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-chktex) package for Sublime Text 3 on Windows 8.1. As part of that I need to install Cygwin and ChkTex.

[Following the instructions](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-chktex#linter-installation), I have first installed Cygwin with `make` and `gcc compile`. Even though it was not mentioned in the instructions, I added `C:\cygwin64\bin` to `%PATH%`.

Then I downloaded ChkTex and saved it in the home directory of Cygwin (`C:\Cygwin64\home\USER` where `USER` in my case is `Fredrik`).

The third step in the instructions is "In the cygwin bash, run `configure` and `make`" but then I don't know what to do. I have tried typing `configure` in Cygwin64 Terminal but get the error message

```
-bash: configure: command not found
```

Then, after some googling, I tried typing `./configure` which resulted in

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the directory before running `configure`. In Cygwin64 Terminal, type

```
cd c:
cd cygwin64/home/USER
cd chktex-1.7.2
configure
make
make install
```

to install ChkTeX.

However, then you will run into the bug that [ChkTex can't handle spaces in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378183/cygwin-make-chktex-command-not-found).